# Is there any way to seprate strings to substrings we choose? like: sin(log(10))

Tags: arrays, c, string, split

Is there any way to submerge a string and put it into an array like:

`y = sin(log(tan(x)))` -> `{"y", "=", "sin", "(", ...}`

no blank space matters like: `sin(x)` = `sin ( x )`

Here's is my code:

```
bool firstDone = 0;
char strr[][4] = { "sin", "cos", "(", ")", "x" };
char str[] = "sin(cos(x))", st[7][5];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (!firstDone) {
        if (strlen(strtok(str, strr[i])) < 4) {
            strcpy(st[i], strtok(str, strr[i]));
            firstDone = 1;
        }
    }
    if (firstDone) {
        if (strlen(strtok(NULL, strr[i])) < 4) {
            strcpy(st[i], strtok(NULL, strr[i]));
        }
    }

}
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    printf("%s, ", st[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's commonly done. It's called tokenization.

Comment: The answer to "Is there a way...?" is usually yes. I assume that since you've added your code to the question that you actually have a more specific question about it. What isn't working? What do you expect?

Comment: See: Tokenization, also Reverse Polish Notation and the Shunting Yard Algorithm.

Comment: The delimiter for strtok is a single character from a set of characters in a string. You seem to be trying to match a string, which is not what it does.  Have a look at strstr.

Comment: Read a good textbook on lexing and parsing, such as the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools.)

Comment: thanks everybody, but can anyone give me a working function so I can understand better for example how to use tokenization in this problem.

Comment: @RetiredNinja See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270933/should-i-answer-is-it-possible-type-of-questions regarding the first part of your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called tokenization.

You can implement one in C like this:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void print_string(const char *begin, const char *end) {
  for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
    putchar(*begin);
  }
}

static void print_tokens(const char *s) {
  const char *p;
  while (*s != '\0') {
    if (isspace(*s)) {
      ++s;
    } else if (isalpha(*s)) {
      for (p = s; isalpha(*s); ++s) {}
      print_string(p, s);
      putchar('\n');
    } else {
      putchar(*s);
      putchar('\n');
      ++s;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  (void)argc; (void)argv;
  print_tokens("sin(log  (tan(x)))");
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sin
(
log
(
tan
(
x
)
)
)
```

Many compilers and interpreters written in C have a tokenizer similar to the one above.

A variant of this is reading the input from a FILE* using [getc(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getc). In that case the [ungetc(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ungetc) function is useful to put back one byte to the input, for example when we figure out that the `(` after the `sin` is not a letter, then we can *ungetc* it back to the input so that the next iteration of the loop will process it.

Some other compilers and interpreters use regular expressions for tokenization, i.e. each token type is specified as a regexp. In your case the regexps would be `\s+`, `[a-zA-Z]+` and `[^\sa-zA-Z]`. The Unix tool *lex* and its GNU implementation [flex(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flex) ([manual](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Ecr4bd/flex-manual/)) can be used to compile those regexps to C.